# Same content for same user and same post in Django Comments not getting saved

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-comments

I am using `django_comments` with Django `1.8`. When a user posts a comment on the same target object(post) with the same content as of the any of his previous comments then it doesn't get saved in the database. Is there any constraint that I am missing?

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by commenting the line `new = self.check_for_duplicate_comment(new)` in the `forms.py` file of `django_comments` package.

This skips calling of the function `check_for_duplicate(...)` that doesn't allow duplicate comments to get created.